# Trying to refresh div with jQuery in MVC f/w

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Hi everyone I have been working on this particular problem for ages by now,plz help.
I have looked at [jQuery: Refresh div after another jquery action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488162/jquery-refresh-div-after-another-jquery-action)
and it does exactly what I want but only once! I have a table generated from db and when I click on delete it deletes the row and refreshes the div but after which none of my jquery functions will work.

```
$('#docs td.delete').click(function() {
    $("#docs tr.itemDetail").hide();
    var i = $(this).parent().attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('kt_docs/deleteDoc'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'id=' + i,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#docs tr.itemDetail").hide();
            $("#f1").html(data); //    wont work twice            
            //$("#docs").load(location.href+" #docs>*"); //works once as well
        }
    });
});
```

in my body I have

```
<fieldset class='step' id='f1'>
    <?php $this->load->view('profile/docs_table'); ?>
</fieldset>
```

profile/docs reads data from db. `<table id='docs'>....</table>`
and my controller:

```
function deleteDoc() {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $this->load->model('documents_model');
    $del = $this->documents_model->deleteDocument($id);    
    return $this->load->view('docs_table');
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you removing any expressions matching $('#docs td.delete') anywhere? If so, consider using $.live(), which will attach your function to ALL matching elements regardless of current or in the future; e.g.

```
$('#docs td.delete').live('click', function() {
    // Do stuff.
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 2):

Try using `bind()` instead of `click()`. The `click()` method won't work on dynamically added elements to the DOM, which is probably why it only works the first time and not after you re-populate it with your updated content.

You should just have to replace

```
$('#docs td.delete').click(function() {
```

with

```
$('#docs td.delete').bind('click', function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you replacing the html elements that have the events on them with the data your getting through ajax? If you end up replacing the td.delete elements, then the new ones won't automatically get the binding.

Comment: Yes I am replacing the #f1 content with same content... I mean with the same table, which has td.delete as well.